# not all images displaying in react native android

Tags: react-native

i am using react native image component and i am getting a url image from rest api. the problem is those images not loading and displaying in android api 16 & 17 but displaying in android api 27 genymotion(both in development and release).

here is the url of the image that is not displaying in android 16 & 17:

http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/tr.png

and this is the url of the image that is loading successfully in android 16 & 17:

https://image.delfoo.com/data/background/food-pizza.jpg

this is my code:

`<Image source={{uri:'http://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/tr.png'}} style={{width:50,height:50}}/>`

when i use onError method in Image component and console that it shows me this error:

SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: {…}, …}

Additional Information

React Native version: 0.59.9

Platform: Android

Development Operating System: Windows

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below code in dependency section of app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.1.0'
```

Comment: It seems to me
You need to mark your answer correctly written